# Material Icon tab missing from the properties window?

Tags: texturing, interface

My checkered sphere missing, the *Materials* tab is missing from the *Properties Window*!

[image]

I don't know how to change the skin of the Minecraft Rig. Is there a reason the checkered sphere is missing?

Comment: Try to select the mesh instead of the bones.

Comment: How do you select mesh? Sorry I nub. XD

Comment: In the 3D viewport you have the wrong object selected, you selected the armature, instead you should select the geometry of the Minecraft character itself, not the rig.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are in Pose Mode, you need to be in Object Mode as shown below:
[image]